For loop inside an omp task
I have this code, parallel odd-even merge sort. I am now trying to optimize it more, and I think a good idea is to parallelize the for loop that is commented, as those comparisons are independent. But, when I parallelize that loop, only worse performance is achieved. I printed the thread ID inside the loop, and only one thread is looping, even if I write num_threads(2)
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp single
    oddEvenMergeSort(newArr, newSize, 0, limit);
}


void oddEvenMergeSort(int *arr, int n, int level, int limit) {
    if (n > 1) {
        int m = n / 2;

        if (level < limit)
        {
            level += 1;
            #pragma omp task shared(arr)
            oddEvenMergeSort(arr, m, level, limit);

            #pragma omp task shared(arr)
            oddEvenMergeSort(arr + m, n - m, level, limit);

            #pragma omp taskwait
            oddEvenMerge(arr, n);
        }
        else {
            oddEvenMergeSort(arr, m, level, limit);

            oddEvenMergeSort(arr + m, n - m, level, limit);

            oddEvenMerge(arr, n);
        }
    }
}

void oddEvenMerge(int *arr, int n) {
    if (n == 1) return;
    if (n == 2) {
        compare(arr, 0, 1);
        return;
    }
    else {
        int *odd = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n / 2));
        int *even = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (n / 2));
        oddEvenSplit(arr, odd, even, n);

        oddEvenMerge(odd, n / 2);

        oddEvenMerge(even, n / 2);

        oddEvenJoin(arr, odd, even, n);


        // #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static, 1)
        for (int i = 1; i < n / 2; i++) {
            printf("Thread %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
            compare(arr, 2 * i - 1, 2 * i);
        }

        free(odd);
        free(even);
    }
}


Maybe you create too many tasks? What is the value of limit? A minimal reproducible example would be very helpful so we can test your program.

Note you can reduce the number of spawned task by removing the second #pragma omp task shared(arr). Indeed, currently, tasks spawn two tasks and then do nothing besides waiting. Tasks introduce a significant overhead since they need to be scheduled dynamically. Note that some CPU have NUMA effect impacting performance of task-based codes. Thus, please share your CPU reference in questions like that. Different OpenMP runtimes also have (very) different behaviour, especially for task scheduling. Thus, please also share the runtime/compiler used in your tests.

By the way, did you enable OpenMP?

You would need to activate nested parallelism (see OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS) but even then I would not bet on performance improvements especially if you are already spawning enough tasks to keep your CPU cores fed. The loop in question is also has very little compute that would benefit from parallelism.

Instead of testing limit, put a final clause on the task: then the task will be executed as ordinary code. That way you avoid the code duplication you have now.

@paleonix I think the active levels are only for having a parallel region inside a parallel region. Recursive task generation always works.

@VictorEijkhout So inside a parallel task does not count as inside a parallel region? Interesting.

@paleonix Yes, the inside of a task counts as "inside a parallel region", but it's the same one that spawned the task. The "active levels" terminology applies to #pragma omp parallel { f() } and void f() { #pragma omp parallel { g(); } }.

@VictorEijkhout what paleonix tried to point out is that #pragma omp parallel masked { t() } with void t() { #pragma omp task { f(); } } and void f() { #pragma omp parallel { g(); } } will also have active-levels-var=2 in g, if max-active-levels-var allows that. This would be the case when uncommenting the parallel directive in oddEvenMerge.

One could add some logic to determine if one is deep enough into the recursion that the tasks are keeping the CPU busy and just parallelize those loops for the first (few) levels of recursion where there isn't enough tasks yet using an if clause on the pragmas. I'm not sure how significant that will be in practice but it could help in theory to avoid oversubscribtion.

@MarcosAlonso which OpenMP implementation do you use? For any LLVM-based OpenMP runtime, you should set KMP_HOT_TEAMS_MAX_LEVEL=2 to avoid the cost of thread creation for the inner parallel region.
